# How an input step in jenkins(using input step plugin) can show the values fetched from a yaml file as a checkboxes on jenkins UI?

Tags: groovy, user-input, jenkins-groovy

Trying to customized the pipeline such that during CI building, input step will ask for the values fetched from a yaml file and showing them live on the Jenkins UI. Once all the values (or keys) are visible on input step then the user can select the keys and proceed further.

```
                def inputResult = input (
                    message: "Select a git tag"
                    id: 'userinput'
                    parameters [[
                        $class: "CascadeChoiceParameter", 
                        choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX', 
                        description: "keys")
                        name: 'get the keys'
                        script: [
                            $class: 'GroovyScript',
                            fallbackScript: [
                                classpath: [],
                                script:
                                    'return["could not find the keys"]'
                            ]
                            script: [
                                classpath: [],
                                script:
                                    """
                                    def yaml = readYaml file: "output.yaml"
                                    def results = []
                                    for (service in yaml.services) {
                                        results.push(service.name + ":") + service.value)
                                    }
                                    return results
                                    """
                
                            ]
                        ]
                        
                    }
                )


yaml is 
services:
-  name: "abc"
   value: "xyz"
```

it is throwing error at service :
missingpropertyexception no such property service for class groovy.lang.binding....

Expected - I need all the name and values displayed as a checkboxes on the input step.

Comment: `service.name + ":") + service.value` there is a `)` hanging around

Comment: Hi @cfrick , Please ignore that ')' it is a type from my side. There are 2 main points here :
1 - Can we do similar type of groovy script in the script block ?
2 - If not, how can I return a list to a checkboxes where the variable which consists the array/list out of the above section and in one of the other jenkins stages ?